# Failed to load resource (Not Found) (Internal Server Error) after uploading website on server

Tags: html, css, upload, console

**PROBLEM SOLVED BY DELETING ALL THE FILES ON THE SERVER AND UPLOADING AGAIN MY WEBSITE!**

[Screenshot of the console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veGgE.jpg)

Hi,

my website looks fine when I open it offline on my browser but after having uploaded it on the server when I go to the web address it only shows the text and images without any formatting and CSS.
I don't know what to do to fix this :\ What could be the problem?

If it can be of help here is the current folder structure of my website:
 "public_html" > 
**css, img, js, mail, scss, vendor**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=yes">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />

  <title>website title</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


  <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
  <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="css/agency-edit.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css/adjustment.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
```

And here some scripts that are at the end of the "body".

```
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
  <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Contact form JavaScript -->
  <script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
  <script src="js/contact_me.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
  <script src="js/agency.min.js"></script>
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you actually upload all of the CSS/JS in the correct relative locations?

Comment: I think so, because when I open the website on my computer everything looks good.

Comment: Can you show us more specificly file structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, it can be:

- Uncorrect relative location (your css and other files are not found by code, check paths of included files)
- Files are not uploaded to server (try to upload them again)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try to re-upload the files again on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I bet if you put a slash `/` in front of all of your local paths, things will magically work for you.

Explanation:

`vendor/` looks in the current folder for the "vendor"  folder.

`/vendor/` looks in the root of the site.

`../vendor/` looks in the parent of my current folder.

`./vendor/` looks "here". (Side note: This is more useful within the server itself when files are referenced by other files in another location for server-side processing.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply!
I have done like you said but after adding a / in front of "vendor" and the other folders the website doesn't show up correctly in the offline version (so I guess it wont work in the online version either?)

Comment: I would expect that as the root of your local is far different than the root of a website. To get the paths to work for both sides, you will need to use a path relative to this file instead of root. To do that, perhaps a screenshot of the folder structure on the server could help us here.

Comment: Thank you for the support, I decided to reupload all the files again and now it works. probably something wasn't uploaded correctly!